# Python on Windows error: python25.dll not found

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I am running Python 2.7 on Windows 7 (on parallels on a Mac running Mountain Lion) and getting a strange error. It has happened both using Python(x,y) and the Enthought Python Distribution (paid version - 64-bit).

Running python from the command line initially works fine (and always does after rebooting the machine).

But, when I try to run my code at the command line as

```
python the_script.py
```

On the first try, I get this error window:
[image: python25.dll missing error]

After that, I get the same error just from typing `python` at the command line.

If I specify the path as `c:\python27\python the_script.py` it works fine.

Here are all the modules I'm loading in my scripts:

```
import numpy as np
import subprocess as sub
import parallel_condor_Jacobian as pcj
import os
import shutil
```

In `parallel_condor_Jacobian` the following modules are loaded:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import subprocess as sub
```

Nothing really out of the ordinary I think!

Is one of these packages somehow dependent on python25.dll?

Fixes I have tried include totally removing python 2.7, reinstalling, and removing all python path stuff from my PATH environment variable and replacing them with c:\python27.

I'm really at a loss here. Happy to provide more relevant information.

Comment: once you start getting errors open up cmd and type `where python` to see which python its looking for

Comment: whoah @JoranBeasley, that's strange! It has placed the current working directory in front of the proper one like: `where python` returns `y:\stuff\local_drive\python.exe` and then `c:\python27\python.exe`. So what would hijack it like that?

Comment: now type `echo %path%` try and log in as a normal user instead of an admin ... since afaik it requires elevated permissions to change your path

Comment: OK. So `where python` returns only `c:\python27\python.exe` until I try running my script. Then it changes to add the local drive. BTW - I should mention the reason the local drive is `y:\...` is that it's mapped to the host Macintosh system. Same thing happens on `c:\ ` though. Running `echo %path%` shows the same results before and after the error. No changes to it (and the local directory is not in `%path%`)

Comment: hmmm that does seem very weird ... can you post the script your running that causes the problem (on pastebin or something?)

Comment: I stuck the scripts at: http://www.talulat.com/pywin/  There are two python files and the main one is Condor_ATC.py. It depends on the other....

Comment: One very hackey solution is `doskey python=C:\python27\python.exe $*`  this is  essentially the equivelent of an alias in other os

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16516/discussion-between-joran-beasley-and-mishaf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the python.exe in the local folder ... and tell your colleagues to upgrade to at least 2.6  :P
and also tell them that the python exe is not portable :P

Comment: Thanks! This portability of the python.exe was dangerous and I forgot my colleague had stuck it in there. Problem Solved!!